# Maximum length of filename length when using GetObjectRequest()

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go

I am unable to download file name with characters greater than 200 when passed through
**ResponseContentDisposition** header in the **GetObjectRequest** method of AWS SDK for Golang. The filename gets trimmed. Is there a limit on the length of characters for a filename?

I tried downloading filename with characters more than 200 on my PC, but there were a few characters that got trimmed while downloading through pres-signed URL.